# Overriding h:outputFormat

Tags: jsf, custom-component, outputformat

I'd like to extend the functionality of `h:outputFormat` JSF (2.2) tag or component. I'd like pass parameters by their name instead of by their order, e.g.:

```
<h2:outputFormat value="This is a ${code} text.">
    <f:param name="code" value="sample" />
</h2:outputFormat>
```

Which classes have I to override?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I've already have a text handling module. This module has an admin GUI for admin users. So admin users can set the text all over the webapp. This module can process parameterized message like above.
I've given a try to the original h:outputFormat but it wasn't success. If the users set text with wrong parameters the original h:oututFormat throws NumberFormatException and I couldn't handle this errorneous case.
So this is the two main reasons.